# How to rewrite the URL using asp.net core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm a desktop developer. But i need to learn how to do web development using ASP.net Core. So i am here now asking question. How do i properly rewrite the URL of my website:

This is the structure of my website

[image]

This is how I Add link to my layout page

```
<li><a asp-action="Index" asp-controller="Home">Home</a></li>
<li><a asp-action="Excel" asp-controller="Excel">Excel</a></li>
```

What is want to do is rewrite this URL

```
http://localhost:64419/Excel/Excel
```

Currently I am using this middleware

```
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Rewrite/
```

And this is my code

```
// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseStatusCodePages();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                var rewrite = new RewriteOptions()

                .AddRewrite(@"ExcelOnly", "Excel/Excel", skipRemainingRules: false);

                app.UseRewriter(rewrite);

                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}"
                    );

                routes.MapRoute(
                   name: "excel",
                   template: "{controller=Excel}/{action=Excel}"
                   );
            });
        }
```

Because of the code above I was able to rewrite the URL into

```
http://localhost:64419/ExcelOnly
```

By simply typing the Link in the URL.

But when I clicked on the Link in the Layout page. The page is loaded but it uses the link `http://localhost:64419/Excel/Excel` how can I properly rewrite the URL.

What are the things I need to search. I can't find a solution. Maybe I'm using the wrong search term. So I decided to ask here.

Thank you.

**Update:**

I was able to redirect the page in the URL i want

with this code

```
var rewrite = new RewriteOptions()
                .AddRedirect("Excel/Excel", "ExcelOnly")
                .AddRewrite(@"ExcelOnly", "Excel/Excel", skipRemainingRules: false);

                app.UseRewriter(rewrite);
```

But is it a good practice? I always need the Controller and the Action in each of my redirect. So if i changed the Action name i also need to change the redirect and rewrite.

And another problem. When I hover the mouse in the link 
it shows the path http://localhost:64419/Excel/Excel so how can I hide this stuff?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> URL rewriting can reduce the performance of an app. Where feasible, you should limit the number and complexity of rules.

If you want to route to `Excel Action` in `Excel Controller` with URL `ExcelOnly`, you could try `Route` like below:

```
    public class ExcelController : Controller
{
    [Route("ExcelOnly")]
    public IActionResult Excel()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

It will generate `<li><a asp-action="Excel" asp-controller="Excel">Excel</a></li>` to

```
<a href="/ExcelOnly">Excel</a>
```

And when you enter `http://localhost:64419/ExcelOnly`, it will route to `Excel` action in `Excel` controller.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. And thank you for telling me the things i need to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

Herewith i mention solution for first problem.
Please put below code in Layout page

```
 <li> <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Excel" asp-action="Excel">Excel</a></li>
```

put below code in startup.cs page

```
   public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseBrowserLink();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        }

        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
```